# AWS cli wrapper, how does it know where your ec2 instances are?

Tags: perl, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, command-line-interface

I'm working with this aws cli wrapper: https://github.com/hirose31/AWS-CLIWrapper

But I can't get it to work, when I try to use "describe instances" the error code says

```
A client error (InvalidInstanceID.NotFound) occurred when calling the DescribeInstances
operation: The instance ID 'i-********' does not exist.
```

(I added the asterisks)

Then I was thinking, it doesn't have my access key and secret key, so how would it know?

I tried setting the endpoint in my constructor too, but to no avail. Can someone tell me how this works?

```
use AWS::CLIWrapper;

my $aws = AWS::CLIWrapper->new(
    region => 'us-west-1',
);

my $res = $aws->ec2('describe-instances', {
        instance_ids => ['i-********'],
       });

if ($res) {
    for my $rs ( @{ $res->{Reservations} }) {
        for my $is (@{ $rs->{Instances} }) {
            print $is->{InstanceId},"\n";
        }
    }
} else {
    warn $AWS::CLIWrapper::Error->{Code};
    warn $AWS::CLIWrapper::Error->{Message};
}
```

I'm trying to get the contents of the command `aws ec2 describe-instances`

Comment: No, that's not access key issue. It tells you the instance is not exist.

Comment: Right but I'm looking at the instance in the AWS console. I set the instance id. To be more clear, I can run these commands in the terminal and get back what I want, I set up a .pem and configured it. But making a script with this module is the problem.

Comment: then you need show the code and command , put in your question

Comment: Oh gosh! I didn't have the right region! I'm in the east... Thanks for being my rubber duck @BMW

Comment: @physicsRiot You should write that as an answer so future visitors know how you solved your problem. Comments on Stack Overflow are not really meant to be permanent and are often deleted by moderators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My ec2 instance is in zone 'us-east-1c' so I updated my constructor to have `region => 'us-east-1'`  (note that I had to leave off the 'c') and this fixed my problem.